# Cannot allocate memory (12)

Tags: 14.04

I'm recently getting an error in Ubuntu14.04 when I try to start a webserver.
The error looks like that:
`Fatal Error Unable to allocate shared memory segment of 67108864 bytes: mmap: Cannot allocate memory (12)`

It happened after I tried to install ownCloud on my server. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: try [this](http://ma.juii.net/blog/fix-allocate-shared-memory-segment-errors-with-php-fcgi) ,if useful

Comment: @Ravan I tried, but it doesn't work... at the moment I try working on `LocalSettings.php`, changing `ini_set` (as written in a comment), but I'm not able to `cat` the file or to save any changes..getting the error `Too many levels of symbolic links`... Any idea whyß

Answer (score 0):

Edit

> /etc/php5/mods-available/opcache.ini

find `opcache.enable_cli=1` change it to `opcache.enable_cli=0` 
if `opcache.enable_cli=1` is not found add the following line `opcache.enable_cli=0`

Comment: seems to be not working, still getting the same error..

Comment: are you running this is a VM. if not run a memtest

Comment: it's a VPS... How du I run it? When running `free`, I see that there are onlyl 20MB total memory available, I think this is the problem... As written as comment above, I tried to change it but am not able to...